# DropDownList and GridView.Row.Count not working together

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

So I have a GridView table with a DropDownList that changes the page size and a Label that displays the number of rows that are on that page. My problem is when the page loads, the value for the lastRowOnPage is zero. And when I click on the drop down items it will display the number for the previous selection. For example, if I select 25 from the list, the label will display "Showing 1 - 10 " when it should say "Showing 1 - 25 ". It does that for all of the selections.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True"
        OnLoad="Page_Load" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="25" Value="25" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="50" Value="50" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="100" Value="100" />                       
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" onSelected="onSelectedData" ... ></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Most of the solutions for issues similar to this say something about if(!IsNotPostBack) and DataBind() but I have that in here.

```
public partial class UserControls_CQGCompanyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView1();
    }
}
protected void onSelectedData(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    int startRowOnPage = (GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize) + 1;
    int lastRowOnPage = startRowOnPage + GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    int totalRows = e.AffectedRows;

    Total1.Text = "Showing " + startRowOnPage.ToString() +
                  " - " + lastRowOnPage + " of " + totalRows;
}
protected void BindGridView1()   
{
try
   if (Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) != null)
    GridView1.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

this.GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
   {
   GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   BindGridView1();
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGridView1();
}     
}
```

What do I need to do?? Please help!

Comment: @Emre That didn't do anything...

Comment: You should have already figured but just writing here.. `OnLoad="Page_Load"` is not necessary.. it just hits server twice. Also `int lastRowOnPage = startRowOnPage + GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
` didn't work..  Needed to use `int lastRowOnPage = startRowOnPage + GridView1.PageSize - 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 protected void onSelectedData(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
 {
    int startRowOnPage = (GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize) + 1;
       int lastRowOnPage = startRowOnPage + GridView1.PageSize - 1;
       int totalRows = e.AffectedRows;

       lastRowOnPage = totalRows < lastRowOnPage ? totalRows : lastRowOnPage;
       startRowOnPage = startRowOnPage > lastRowOnPage ? (int)(totalRows / GridView1.PageSize) * GridView1.PageSize + 1 : startRowOnPage;

       Label1.Text = "Showing " + startRowOnPage.ToString() +
                              " - " + lastRowOnPage + " of " + totalRows;
            }
```

Comment: Holy cow that was super simple! Thank you so much!! Works like a charm. Why didn't I think of that...